# Load issue with .tmx file

Tags: xamarin, cocossharp

I've got an issue when I try to load a .tmx file in a CCTileMap CocosSharp object.

Here is the code :

```
                layer2 = new CCLayer();
                CCTileMap tileMap;
                tileMap = new CCTileMap("TestCCS.Droid.Assets/TileMaps/TestTile2.tmx");

                layer2.AddChild(tileMap);
                this.AddChild(layer2);
```

I tried :

```
                tileMap = new CCTileMap("TestCCS.Droid.Assets.TileMaps.TestTile2.tmx");
```

or :

```
                tileMap = new CCTileMap("Assets.TileMaps.TestTile2.tmx");
```

The TestTile2.tmx file build Action is set to "Embedded resource"

And this my solution explorer :

[image]

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a way to load the TileMap file.

The solution I found :

- save the TileMap file in .xml format in Tiled software.
- save the .tsx file in .xml format.
- I use this code to load the tile map file :

  ```
              layer2 = new CCLayer();
              CCTileMap tileMap;

              CCTileMapInfo mi = new CCTileMapInfo("TestTile2.xml");
              tileMap = new CCTileMap(mi); 

              layer2.AddChild(tileMap);
              this.AddChild(layer2);
  ```

Where "TestTile2.xml" is an android asset.

- every tile of layers must have an Id.
  I had tiles without "gid", I had to set them to a transparent gid.

Hope this will help others !